# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0034 seconds.)

Tags: mysql, join

I Want to join the two tables data and one location and the other one is trip when ever i query for the the one table its show the data but whenever i use the query to join two rows it wont fetch the table result

Here is my query

```
SELECT trip.Trip_Name ,trip.Trip_ID , trip.Trip_Date , location.Location_Name , location.Location_ID 
FROM location 
INNER JOIN trip ON trip.Trip_ID = location.Location_ID
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Assuming you are joining on the correct fields and the condition is true then the query will work. Can you give an example of where you don't think it works.

Comment: Please, share table schema of trip and location. Perhaps, you are matching wrong fields.

Comment: Then there is no trip_id in the trip table that is the same as a location_id in the location table. To be honest it doesn't sound like these two id columns should be related, any more than person.person_id would equal address.address_id. Are you sure that a trip doesn't take place to a location and hence the trip table has a location_id column ?

Comment: at-least add some sample data ,without sample no one can give you an answer.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS You were told to do this before you finished posting your question, weren't you?

Answer (score 0):

i think trip_id is not the same as location_id

the trip table containt trip's information
and the location containt the location's information

so in order to make join you should make a new column named "location_id" in trip as foreign key 
and location.location_id as primary key